# ID book with an autopsy in a snowy village

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've only read the first chapter months ago, and can't remember much more about the synopsis other than that opening scene:

From the AI (I think it was AI or an advanced human) point of view in chapter one:

He rides a train to a snowy little village. The Lord of the village has died. The POV character is a doctor and is supposed to perform an autopsy. The son of the Lord questions the cause of  death.

The POV character mentally moves from what's happening in front of him to other consciousness within the collective - an EMT tech, or something manning a computer.

When performing the autopsy the POV character finds something in the deceased and puts it in a vial or jar, I believe the thing moves around.

That's all I can remember, but it's stuck with me nearly a year later and I would really like to read the rest of it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your posts if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[*Leech*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/59807968-leech?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=GkGhh5DT5b&rank=1), by Hiron Ennes. Goodreads summary:

> In an isolated chateau, as far north as north goes, the baron’s doctor
> has died. The doctor’s replacement has a mystery to solve: discovering
> how the Institute lost track of one of its many bodies.
>
> For hundreds of years the Interprovincial Medical Institute has grown
> by taking root in young minds and shaping them into doctors, replacing
> every human practitioner of medicine. The Institute is here to help
> humanity, to cure and to cut, to cradle and protect the species from
> the apocalyptic horrors their ancestors unleashed.
>
> In the frozen north, the Institute's body will discover a competitor
> for its rung at the top of the evolutionary ladder. A parasite is
> spreading through the baron's castle, already a dark pit of secrets,
> lies, violence, and fear. The two will make war on the battlefield of
> the body. Whichever wins, humanity will lose again.

The autopsy with a creature found in the body occurs early on:

> After exploring the optic canal, I manage to grip the growth with the
> tips of my forceps. It resists me at first, but I twist, plucking tiny
> tendrils from walls of connective tissue. A substantial part of the
> thing pulls loose, and the hairs widen, meeting in black confluences
> toward what must be the body of some sort of organism. With a soft
> popping sound, I pull it from the bone, past the socket, and into the
> cold air.

The shared consciousness is described with one body in an EMT-like role:

> Only one body, exhausted from a day’s work in the Inultan governor’s
> aeronautic laboratory, gives way under the weight of my surprise. In
> the dusty red light of the dirigible bay, I stumble, the stretcher’s
> handles slipping from my grasp.
>
> “What
> is wrong with you?” The stretcher’s other carrier, a hard-faced
> engineer, bends to help his fallen comrade. “Ten minutes past you lift
> half an engine off this man, and now you can’t lift him?”

Comment: This is it!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been trying to figure it out for a long time.

Comment: @Holley Awesome that this is it. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick at the top left of it so it turns green.

Comment: @JudithJones  I checked the check mark and it's now green, was that the correct thing?